# How to solve $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x^x - 1}{\ln(x) + x - 1}$ using L'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How could I solve

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x^x - 1}{\ln(x) + x - 1}
\end{align*}
$$

using L'hôpital? Analysing the limit we have $0^0$ on the numerator (which would require using logs) but also $- \infty$ on the denominator.

I know that $[x^x]' = x^x (\ln (x) + 1)$, that may be helpful at some point.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1$, and the denominator tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Are you sure you need L'Hopital? Suppose for a moment that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x$ is finite; then the numerator would have a finite limit and the denominator would have an infinite limit, so L'Hopital would not apply. Is it actually finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} {x^x }  = e^{x \ln x} = e^{x/(1/\ln x)}
$$

By L'Hôpital rule, $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x}{1/\ln x} = {-x\log(x)^2} = 0$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} {x^x }  = 1$$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} {\ln(x) + x - 1}= -\infty
$$

The L'Hôpital is merely suitable to case: $0/0,\infty/\infty,1^\infty $

So
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x^x - 1}{\ln(x) + x - 1} = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed simply as
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x^{x} - 1}{\log x + x - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\exp(x\log x) - 1}{x\log x}\cdot\frac{x\log x}{\log x + x - 1}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{x\log x}{\log x + x - 1}\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
Here we have used the standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log x = 0,\,\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\log x = -\infty,\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\exp(x) - 1}{x} = 1$$